# I cant change background color of input

Tags: css, sass

Hello guys I am not able to change background color of input. It inherits white color from the browser class - 'user agent stylesheet' which overrides my class and properties. The problem is I tried workound defining input what was advised on forum but did not help.

```
input {
cursor: inherit;
} 

scss: 

    .authentication-form {
       &__input {
        @include formBorder;
        background-color: darkblue;
        padding: 1.5rem;
       }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form class="authentication-form" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="authentication-form__card">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input class="authentication-form__input" name="username" type="text">
        <input class="authentication-form__input" name="password" type="password">
        <button class="authentication-form__button" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please share your markup too.

Comment: is `.authentication-form` in scss file nested inside any selector?

Comment: no it is not nested

Comment: Are the fields being auto filled by the browser? That’s because browsers apply some additional styles to these fields and will override the background color you’ve set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this example for styling inputs. You will have to write `input[type=text]` in your CSS or SASS.

```css
input[type=text] {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text">
```

Check out this example for your application:

```css
input {
cursor: inherit;
} 

input[type=text] {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

input[type=password] {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

scss: 

    .authentication-form {
       &__input {
        @include formBorder;
        background-color: darkblue;
        padding: 1.5rem;
       }
    }
```

```html
<form class="authentication-form" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="authentication-form__card">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input class="authentication-form__input" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
        <input class="authentication-form__input" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
        <button class="authentication-form__button" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```